# How to make a function available to parent shell?

Tags: windows, bash, shell, cygwin

I am writing a BASH script (let's call it `installScript.sh`) to `install` a function in users's environment.

1. First i append the function to user's `~/.bashrc`
2. After that in the same script, i am trying to 'source' `~/.bashrc`

I want the function be available to user after `installScript.sh` is executed.

Comment: You are not able to do this. Because, there is no way to get the functions in child shell.

Comment: Why don't you just ask your users to source your `installScript.sh` instead of executing it? Even when sourced, it could define the function for the current shell and also append its definition to your user's `~/.bashrc` (after checking it is not already there) for use in new shells.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet  It will work for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just ask your users to source your `installScript.sh` instead of executing it? Even when sourced, it could define the function for the current shell and also append its definition to your user's `~/.bashrc` (after checking it is not already there) for use in new shells.
                    – Renaud Pacalet